# Insert records to Heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, heroku

How can I insert new records to Heroku database. I have successfully uploaded my application and  database structure. Now I need to insert some records so it could work. I tried to use `seeds.rb` but without any success. `db:push` and `db:seed` don't give any success. The database is always empty. Is there any heroku tool available which I could use to see database structure and insert data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

You have a few options. You can run `heroku run rake db:seed`.

Or assuming Postgres, try

```
heroku pg:psql
```

And run your SQL commands from there. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql) for more.

I was also able to connect my IDE to my databases on Heroku. I am using RubyMine, so it was a matter of using the right JDBC URL to make that happen.

Comment: @Cristiano if you are alive please accept this answer :P

Answer (score 1):

> You can use below command for insert record to Heroku server
>
> `heroku run rails c`
>
> Example:-
>
> suppose you have one table is employee and field are first_name.
>
> Now open a command line and call this command
>
> `heroku run rails c`
>
> After call insert command
>
> `Employee.create(first_name: "admin")`